# Objective C: Custom spinning animator class in form of a propeller

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiactivityindicatorview

I basically want my own animator shown on screen while loading stuff. I want a propeller (which should rotate) on top of a fixed gear ring image. The idea is to instantiate an object with a specific frame defining the size of the loading propeller. And then start and stop the spinning like with the normal spinner.

But in my view nothing gets displayed. I am new to programming my own views and how to layout them in the sense of how to put them in the center of the screen and make them the correct size. So I guess my errors are in setting the frames and centers correct, but I have no idea. Maybe you can help:

This is my loading propeller class:

```
@implementation FMLoadingPropeller

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.hidden = YES;

        _movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        _movablePropeller.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PropWhite"];
        _movablePropeller.frame = self.frame;

        _fixedPropellerPart = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        _fixedPropellerPart.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GearringBlue"];
        _fixedPropellerPart.frame = self.frame;

        [self addSubview:_fixedPropellerPart];
        [self addSubview:_movablePropeller];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startPropeller
{
    //_movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    //_movablePropeller.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MovablePropeller"];
    //[self addSubview:self.movablePropeller];
    self.hidden = NO;

    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(2 * M_PI)];
    rotation.cumulative = true;
    rotation.duration = 1.2f; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = INFINITY; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.

    [self.movablePropeller.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.movablePropeller.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
}

- (void)stopPropeller
{
    self.hidden = YES;

    [self.movablePropeller.layer removeAllAnimations];
}

@end
```

And this is how it is instantiated and started:

```
self.loadingPropeller = [[FMLoadingPropeller alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 200, 200)];
self.loadingPropeller.center=self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:self.loadingPropeller];
[self.loadingPropeller startPropeller];
```

But nothing appears on the screen...

**EDIT:**
Now it appears on the screen but in the very lower right corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong frame when creating the two image views. Remember that a view's frame needs to be relative to its parent.

Change:

```
_movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

to:

```
_movablePropeller = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
```

Also remove the line:

```
_movablePropeller.frame = self.frame;
```

The frame was already set in the `initWithFrame` call.

Also confirm that the images are actually being loaded. It's possible you forget to add the images to the app bundle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Ok I've changed all that and the images are loaded. But they are shown way off screen in the lower right corner of my main view. I changed the init call from the main view to the edited part in my first comment but nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

You need right center for view

Right center will appear after show view controller and load all subview

You will help method [viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews)

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.loadingPropeller.center = self.view.center; // changed you x,y
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.loadingPropeller = [[FMLoadingPropeller alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingPropeller];
    [self.loadingPropeller startPropeller];
}
```